# SwiftUI - ColorPicker - Wheel Size

Tags: swiftui, color-picker, ios14

I'm using ColorPicker. I have a problem with the size of the Wheel.
I want it bigger.
I'm using Xcode 12.1. Hope that someone can help me. Thank you.

These is my code:

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var bgColor = Color.blue
    var body: some View {
        ColorPicker("Set the background color", selection: $bgColor)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(bgColor)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is SwiftUI internals - standard control. If you want custom - create representable of UIColorPickerViewController.

Comment: @Asperi . I created it, but it had a problem too. I cannot close it because the close button wasn't showed, and couldn't pull to close the view.
If I use ColorPicker, it will present a picker with the close button.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can scale the color wheel with a `scaleEffect`.

[image]

Comment: Nice bonus tip with .labelIsHidden(), too